# Get data from tableView row data (unexpectedly found nil)

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I am populating a tableView with an array but I can't seem to set the textLabel property using the row's object. Here's the relevant code:

```
let object = realMatches[indexPath.row]

userName = object["first_name"] as! String

cell.textLabel?.text = userName

return cell
```

I get the following error when I try to set the userName variable (which will later be used to set the cell.textLabel property): `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

My realMatches array is returning results so I know the array is not nil. I think the issue is that I don't have a "first name" property in my Matches table. It's located in my User table, but I have a Pointer value in the Matches table that points to the corresponding user. I'm using Parse for my backend.

I tried using a lengthy PFQuery to get the object's first_name but it doesn't seem to pull any results:

```
 var objectUser1 = object["user1"] as! PFUser
            var objectUser2 = object["user2"] as! PFUser

            var userQuery = PFQuery(className: "User")
            userQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: objectUser1.objectId!)

            var userQuery2 = PFQuery(className: "User")
            userQuery2.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: objectUser2.objectId!)

            var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([userQuery, userQuery2])
            query.includeKey("user1")
            query.includeKey("user2")
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    println(error)
                } else {

                    if results != nil {

                        for result in results!{

                            userName = result["first_name"] as! String
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any ideas on how I can properly set the cell's textLabel property to the match's first name?

Thanks!

Edit: Adding the data structure of realMatches. Here is the output from when I println(realMatches):

```
<Match: 0x7fa03b5a6610, objectId: Fq2OAOeggC, localId: (null)> {
    user1 = "<PFUser: 0x7fa03b75e7b0, objectId: aElMSjGRxM>";
    user2 = "<PFUser: 0x7fa03b7b9310, objectId: lJTRi8el8w>";
}, <Match: 0x7fa03b561d80, objectId: KDJ6hG1V4f, localId: (null)> {
    user1 = "<PFUser: 0x7fa03b7b9ca0, objectId: aElMSjGRxM>";
    user2 = "<PFUser: 0x7fa03b47d670, objectId: w1uKRErtDm>";
}]
```

Here's the actual backend data structure:

Match table:
-objectID
-user1 (Pointer)
-user2 (Pointer)

User table:
-objectID
-first_name

Comment: Can you post the bit of code where you actually try to set the label? in the code you have right now you are assigning a value to a variable but I can't see you assigning that value to a cell item at the moment.

Comment: Without knowing the data structure of the realMatches its hard to tell where things felt apart.

Comment: Sure. The error actually does occur on that line `userName = object["first_name"] as! String` but I'll post some more code

Comment: I updated the question with the actual data structure. Hope this helps! Thanks everyone for the replies so far.